# Is there any method of backing up Google Drive files in some sort of versioning system?

Tags: backup, google-drive, google-workspace

Is there any method of backing up Google Drive files in some sort of versioning system that would allow me to revert files back to defined points in time?

**Backstory**

My company is utilizing Google Drive for our shared files. Each user has their own Drive account. In addition, we have a corporate Drive account which holds documents which are shared to each user. Each folder is shared to different users depending on their permissions and positions in the company. Many users are able to add files, and updated folders within this shared Drive account. This is fine.

What is not fine, is when someone deletes something that they shouldn't. I have little to no way of knowing when I file is deleted wrongfully. Furthermore, anything that gets deleted goes into the trash bin of the file's creator, so I can't just restore it from the trash.

**What I have tried**

I currently have this corporate drive account synced up to my personal computer through the Google Drive application. Each night, I run a backup on the file using Windows "Backup and Restore." This allows me to at least get back files that are lost, but I a cleaner method than this. It's very possible that I may not have the very latest version of a document on my computer when the utility runs.

Comment: Pay for a service like Backupify?  https://www.backupify.com/products/google-apps-backup

Comment: I may give them a try.  Every Google search I tried for backing up Google Drive always yielded results for backing up documents to google drive. :-|

Comment: I'm pretty sure that paid Dropbox accounts have this feature built in, without having to do anything extra.